# How to access a DurableEntityClient in an injected class with Azure Durable Functions

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an Azure Functions project that leverages Dependency Injection (`Startup.cs` injects services based on the different interfaces).  Those services that implement the interfaces are using constructor dependency injection as well.

In one of those implementations, I want to call a method on a Durable Entity, but I prefer not to make the `DurableEntityClient` part of the method signature (as other implementations might not need the EntityClient at all).  So therefore, I was hoping to see that `IDurableEntityClient` injected in the constructor of my class.

But it turns out the value is `null`.  Wondering if this is something that is supported and feasible?  (to have a DI-friendly way of injecting classes that want to get the EntityClient for the Functions runtime they are running in)

Some code snippets:

**Startup.cs**

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IReceiver, TableReceiver>();
```

**Actual Function**

```cs
public class ItemWatchHttpTrigger
{
    private IReceiver _receiver;

    public ItemWatchHttpTrigger(IReceiver receiver)
    {
        _receiver = receiver;
    }

    [FunctionName("item-watcher")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "item/{itemId}")]
        HttpRequest request, string itemId, [DurableClient] IDurableEntityClient client, ILogger logger)
    {
        // Actual implementation
    }
}
```

**Referenced class**

```cs
public class TableReceiver : IReceiver
{
    private IDurableEntityClient _entityClient;

    public TableReceiver(IDurableEntityClient client)
    {
        _entityClient = client; // client is null :(
    }
}
```

Comment: `IDurableEntityClient` is bind as as a binding parameter. I don't think you can use inject in constructor via DI. You can expose a method in `IReceiver` method to accept `IDurableEntityClient` which can be passed by the invoker of `IReceiver`.

Comment: I agree that would be a workaround, but it's not one I like, as I believe the `IDurableEntityClient` is something that is part of the implementation, and should not be part of the interface declaration.  The best way would be something like `DurableEntityClient.GetFromContext()` in the SDK

Comment: Not sure as I've not used it, but it seems that you can inject `IDurableClientFactory` via `services.AddDurableTask();` and retrieve/create a new `IDurableClient` client. `IDurableClient` inherits from `IDurableEntityClient `. See [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask/ContextInterfaces/IDurableClient.cs). Check if you can invoke the method exposed by `IDurableEntityClient` on retrieved object from factory.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to post this as answer, as I got this in reply to my github issue.  Will write it out. tx

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/1616#issuecomment-748529560

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the answer of my github issue, it seems it is possible to inject this in Startup, since the `2.4.0` version of the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask` package:

Some code snippets:

**Startup.cs**

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IReceiver, TableReceiver>();
builder.Services.AddDurableClientFactory();
```

**Referenced class**

```cs
public class TableReceiver : IReceiver
{
    private IDurableEntityClient _entityClient;

    public TableReceiver(IDurableClientFactory entityClientFactory, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _entityClient = entityClientFactory.CreateClient(new DurableClientOptions
            {
                TaskHub = configuration["TaskHubName"]
            });
    }
}
```

[Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/1616#issuecomment-748529560)

Comment: This works well, thanks! Though I don't think you meant to pass in `IDurableEntityClient`  in the params as it's unused and still null in this case.

Comment: Thanks, Murray - you're right.  Will update the sample code.